# Using nzsql commands in aginity

Tags: netezza, aginity, nzsql

I'm working with Netezza on Aginity workbench on my windows computer. I'm wondering how I can use nzsql commands such as `\l` to get a list of databases as shows on this site: http://netezzaonline.blogspot.com/2013/10/netezza-cheat-sheets.html near the bottom of the page.

I would also like to use the `nzload` command for getting data into the Netezza appliance.

How can I use these commands on Aginity? Is there a built in terminal that understands these commands? I've been looking everywhere for this. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To you first question, the short answer is: No

The Nzsql is a command-shell for Netezza that enables the execution of sql and lets you run other Pre-build commands against the appliance.
Aginity is a GUI on top of the appliance with many of the same capabilities and more, but accessed through a mouse and some menus.
You can say that command-shells are the predecessors of GUI clients, but they still play a great part in automation.
That being said, just do a ‘select * from _v_database’ as a replacement of \l

To your second question the answer is No as well, but you are fully compensated by the external table syntax:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/c_load_transient_external_tables.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. WHen I do a `Select * from _V_DATABASES` I get an error stating ERROR: relation does not exist DATABASE.SCHEMA._V_DATABASES

Comment: Sorry, it’s without the ‘s’ at the end, I have corrected my answer